# MS Access 2010 SQL query is rounding automatically to whole numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

All,

I'm running the SQL query below in MS Access 2010. Everything works fine except that the "a.trans_amt" column is rounded to a whole number (i.e. the query returns 12.00 instead of 12.15 or 96.00 instead of 96.30). Any ideas? I'd like it to display 2 decimal points. I tried using the ROUND function but didn't have any success.

Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO [2-Matched Activity] ( dbs_eff_date, batch_id_r1, jrnl_name, 
ledger, entity_id_s1, account_s2, intercompany_s6, trans_amt, 
dbs_description, icb_name, fdt_key, combo )
SELECT a.dbs_eff_date, 
a.batch_id_r1, 
a.jrnl_name, 
a.ledger, 
a.entity_id_s1, 
a.account_s2, 
a.intercompany_s6, 
a.trans_amt, 
a.dbs_description, 
a.icb_name, 
a.fdt_key, 
a.combo
FROM [1-ICB Daily Activity] AS a 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
b.dbs_eff_date, 
b.batch_id_r1, 
b.jrnl_name, 
sum(b.trans_amt) AS ["trans_amt"], 
b.icb_name 
FROM [1-ICB Daily Activity] AS b 
GROUP BY dbs_eff_date, batch_id_r1, jrnl_name, icb_name 
HAVING sum(trans_amt) = 0
)  AS b 
ON (a.dbs_eff_date = b.dbs_eff_date) AND (a.batch_id_r1 = b.batch_id_r1) AND 
(a.jrnl_name = b.jrnl_name) AND (a.icb_name = b.icb_name);
```

Comment: What is the data type of `trans_amt` in the source and destination tables?

Comment: @SunKnight0 It's "Number" for both the source and destination tables.

Comment: "Number" does not mean anything. Are the fields an integer number type (like integer or long integer) or a decimal number type (like single or double).

Comment: @SunKnight0 ok. Source table is "Decimal" and destination appears to be "Long Integer". Is this my problem? Should they both be decimal?

Comment: I would not use decimal for either. I would use single. But your problem is definitely that your destination table is long integer.

Comment: @SunKnight0 That worked. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are attempting to append decimal precise values to an integer column. While MS Access does not raise a type exception it will implicitly reduce precision to fit the destination storage. To avoid these undesired results, set the precision type ahead of time.

According to [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208866(v=office.12).aspx), the MS Access database engine maintains the following numeric types:

```
REAL        4 bytes     A single-precision floating-point value with a range of ...
FLOAT       8 bytes     A double-precision floating-point value with a range of ...
SMALLINT    2 bytes     A short integer between – 32,768 and 32,767.
INTEGER     4 bytes     A long integer between – 2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.
DECIMAL    17 bytes     An exact numeric data type that holds values ...
```

And the MS Access GUI translates these as [Field Sizes](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33) in table design interface where the default format of Number is *Long Integer* type.

```
Byte           — For integers that range from 0 to 255. Storage requirement is a single byte.    
Integer        — For integers that range from -32,768 to +32,767. Storage requirement is two bytes.    
Long Integer   — For integers that range from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 ...    
Single         — For numeric floating point values that range from -3.4 x 1038 to ...    
Double         — For numeric floating point values that range from -1.797 x 10308 to ...
Replication ID — For storing a GUID that is required for replication...
Decimal        — For numeric values that range from -9.999... x 1027 to +9.999...
```

Therefore, in designing your database, schema, and tables, select the appropriate values to accommodate your needed precision. If not using the MS Access GUI program, you can define type in a DDL command:

```
CREATE TABLE [2-Matched Activity] (
    ...
    trans_amt DOUBLE,
    ...
)
```

If table already exists consider altering design with another DDL command.

```
ALTER TABLE [2-Matched Activity] ALTER COLUMN trans_amt DOUBLE
```

Do note: if you run `CREATE` and `ALTER` commands in Query Design window, no prompts or confirmation will occur but changes will render.